# Can I use a GraphQL union for plain strings?

Tags: graphql

In Graphql, I can create a `union` such as the following:

```
union SearchResult = Book | Movie
```

Is there a way I can do this for plain strings? Something like this:

```
union AccountRole = "admin" | "consumer"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid you cannot do that because it is what defined by the specification.

From the union syntax mentioned at specification [here](https://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#sec-Unions) , the part that you want to change should follow the [Names](https://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#NameStart) syntax , which the first character is only allow to be upper case letter,  lower case latter or `_`

*(i.e. the characters set as follows)*

> A B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M
> N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z
> a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m
> n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z _